# How can I correct two-finger scrolling on a Linux VM under OSX?

Tags: linux, macos, terminal, scrolling, vmware-fusion

An earlier poster posted some of my concern at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/235029/in-terminal-how-to-exit-the-two-fingers-history-scrolling-mode, and I am grateful; I now know how to get the desired effect (i.e. scroll through a terminal's output instead of shell history on my Mac Terminal application). That answered one half of what I wanted to address.

The second portion of that behavior is that the behavior I don't want (scrolling through command history) is occurring with a Linux Mint ?Gnome-Terminal? on a virtual machine under VMware Fusion. I believe that the guest has VMware tools installed.

Am I able to get what the OP in the referenced question wanted for Mac's built-in Terminal application, i.e. two-finger scrolling scrolls up and down through output, not shell command history?